# How to get a intersection from two binary tree in c++

Tags: c++, tree, binary-tree, intersection

I'm trying to create a **recursive function** that return a tree binary intersection *(the sames node position in both tree, isn't important the number of the node)* pass a tree for explicit parameter. My problem is the function no return the correct intersection binary tree.

i is the tree I'll get when the function finish.

```
intersection (Tree<int>  &i,Tree<int>  &a1,Tree<int>  &a2){

            if (not a1.is_empty() and not a2.is_empty()){
                Tree<int> a1_left;
                Tree<int> a1_right;
                int x = a1.root();
                a1.son(,a1_right);

                Tree<int> a2_left;
                Tree<int> a2_right;
                a2.son(a2_left,a2_right);

                if(not a1_left.is_empty() and not a2_left.is_empty()) {
                    intersection(i,a1_left, a2_left);
                }
                if(not a1_right.is_empty() and not a2_right.is_empty()) {
                    intersection(i,a1_right, a2_right);
                }
                if (a1_right.is_empty() and a2_right.is_empty() and a1_left.is_empty() and a2_left.is_empty()) {
                    i.plant(x,a1_left,a1_right);
                }
                i.plant(x,a1_left,a1_right);
            }
```

I would appreciate any possible solution, even in pseudocode.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Are you actually using the `ciso646` header? It's better to just use `&&`, etc., instead.

Comment: The function no return the correct tree. I took three days trying and have tried a lot of cases but I don't find a solution. Thank's

Comment: I need a pseudocode, for I understand better the solution.